# Get URL parameters from a string in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, url, parsing, parameters

I've got a string in .NET which is actually a URL.  I want an easy way to get the value from a particular parameter.

Normally, I'd just use `Request.Params["theThingIWant"]`, but this string isn't from the request.  I can create a new `Uri` item like so:

```
Uri myUri = new Uri(TheStringUrlIWantMyValueFrom);
```

I can use `myUri.Query` to get the query string...but then I apparently have to find some regexy way of splitting it up.

Am I missing something obvious, or is there no built in way to do this short of creating a regex of some kind, etc?

Answer (score 652, accepted):

Use static `ParseQueryString` method of `System.Web.HttpUtility` class that returns `NameValueCollection`.

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://www.example.com?param1=good&param2=bad");
string param1 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("param1");
```

Check documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx

Comment: This doesn't seem to detect the first parameter. eg parsing "http://www.google.com/search?q=energy+edge&rls=com.microsoft:en-au&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1" doesn't detect the parameter q

Comment: @Andrew
I confirm. It's strange (bug?). You coul still use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get(0)` though and it will extract first parameter.
`

Comment: Any .NET tool to build a parameterized query url?

Comment: When trialling this myself, the signature appears to have changed to this: HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).GetValues("param1").First()

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'HttpUtility' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: This is not working properly in my case I have a query. I have URL "https://test.com/page?time=2022031&&user=test+2fa@gmail.com". And I am trying to fetch "user" querystring. The result return by this approach is "test 2fa@gmail.com" i.e. it's removing the + sign from the user name. Any idea why it's not working

Comment: @AshishShukla: It url encoding, `[space]` -> `+`.  Then `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` decoding it

Comment: @DmitrySokolov you need to add a reference to `System.Web`, then you can add `using System.Web` and access the function in your code with `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`.

Answer (score 63):

This is probably what you want

```
var uri = new Uri("http://domain.test/Default.aspx?var1=true&var2=test&var3=3");
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);

var var2 = query.Get("var2");
```

Comment: I used your code and this to get the url: var url = req.HttpContext.Request.GetEncodedUrl(); Thanks!

Answer (score 44):

Here's another alternative if, for any reason, you can't or don't want to use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()`.

This is built to be somewhat tolerant to "malformed" query strings, i.e. `http://test/test.html?empty=` becomes a parameter with an empty value. The caller can verify the parameters if needed.

```
public static class UriHelper
{
    public static Dictionary<string, string> DecodeQueryParameters(this Uri uri)
    {
        if (uri == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("uri");

        if (uri.Query.Length == 0)
            return new Dictionary<string, string>();

        return uri.Query.TrimStart('?')
                        .Split(new[] { '&', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .Select(parameter => parameter.Split(new[] { '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                        .GroupBy(parts => parts[0],
                                 parts => parts.Length > 2 ? string.Join("=", parts, 1, parts.Length - 1) : (parts.Length > 1 ? parts[1] : ""))
                        .ToDictionary(grouping => grouping.Key,
                                      grouping => string.Join(",", grouping));
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
[TestClass]
public class UriHelperTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void DecodeQueryParameters()
    {
        DecodeQueryParametersTest("http://test/test.html", new Dictionary<string, string>());
        DecodeQueryParametersTest("http://test/test.html?", new Dictionary<string, string>());
        DecodeQueryParametersTest("http://test/test.html?key=bla/blub.xml", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "key", "bla/blub.xml" } });
        DecodeQueryParametersTest("http://test/test.html?eins=1&zwei=2", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "eins", "1" }, { "zwei", "2" } });
        DecodeQueryParametersTest("http://test/test.html?empty", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "empty", "" } });
        DecodeQueryParametersTest("http://test/test.html?empty=", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "empty", "" } });
        DecodeQueryParametersTest("http://test/test.html?key=1&", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "key", "1" } });
        DecodeQueryParametersTest("http://test/test.html?key=value?&b=c", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "key", "value?" }, { "b", "c" } });
        DecodeQueryParametersTest("http://test/test.html?key=value=what", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "key", "value=what" } });
        DecodeQueryParametersTest("http://www.google.com/search?q=energy+edge&rls=com.microsoft:en-au&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1%22",
            new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "q", "energy+edge" },
                { "rls", "com.microsoft:en-au" },
                { "ie", "UTF-8" },
                { "oe", "UTF-8" },
                { "startIndex", "" },
                { "startPage", "1%22" },
            });
        DecodeQueryParametersTest("http://test/test.html?key=value;key=anotherValue", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "key", "value,anotherValue" } });
    }

    private static void DecodeQueryParametersTest(string uri, Dictionary<string, string> expected)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Uri(uri).DecodeQueryParameters();
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.Count, parameters.Count, "Wrong parameter count. Uri: {0}", uri);
        foreach (var key in expected.Keys)
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(parameters.ContainsKey(key), "Missing parameter key {0}. Uri: {1}", key, uri);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected[key], parameters[key], "Wrong parameter value for {0}. Uri: {1}", parameters[key], uri);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: helpful for Xamarin project, where HttpUtility is unavailable

Comment: That's a very useful extension that can be adapted for partial URIs, as well. I'd suggest adding a Uri.UnescapeDataString() to the parameter values or rename the method to something other than "decode" if they aren't actually decoded. `?empty=` isn't a malformed query string. It just has a parameter with an empty string as the value. That's completely normal, so thanks for taking that into account.

Comment: This does not match the behavior of `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()` because it does not perform proper decoding of the values.  As noted in the expected result test cases `{ "startPage", "1%22" }` the value is still percent encoded but would be `1"` if it was parsed by HttpUtility class.

Answer (score 17):

Looks like you should loop over the values of `myUri.Query` and parse it from there.

```
 string desiredValue;
 foreach(string item in myUri.Query.Split('&'))
 {
     string[] parts = item.Replace("?", "").Split('=');
     if(parts[0] == "desiredKey")
     {
         desiredValue = parts[1];
         break;
     }
 }
```

I wouldn't use this code without testing it on a bunch of malformed URLs however.  It might break on some/all of these:

- `hello.html?`
- `hello.html?valuelesskey`
- `hello.html?key=value=hi`
- `hello.html?hi=value?&b=c`
- etc

Answer (score 15):

@Andrew and @CZFox

I had the same bug and found the cause to be that parameter one is in fact: `http://www.example.com?param1` and not `param1` which is what one would expect.

By removing all characters before and including the question mark fixes this problem. So in essence the `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` function only requires a valid query string parameter containing only characters after the question mark as in:

```
HttpUtility.ParseQueryString ( "param1=good&param2=bad" )
```

My workaround:

```
string RawUrl = "http://www.example.com?param1=good&param2=bad";
int index = RawUrl.IndexOf ( "?" );
if ( index > 0 )
    RawUrl = RawUrl.Substring ( index ).Remove ( 0, 1 );

Uri myUri = new Uri( RawUrl, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
string param1 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString( myUri.Query ).Get( "param1" );`
```

Comment: When the URI is instantiated I get the error "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined."  I don't think this solution works as intended.

Comment: @PaulMatthews, you are correct. At the time of this given solution, I was using the older .net framework 2.0. To confirm, your statement, I copied and pasted this solution into LINQPad v2 by Joseph Albahara and received the same error you mentioned.

Comment: @PaulMatthews, To fix, remove the line that reads Uri myUri = new Uri( RawUrl ); and merely pass RawUrl to the last statement as in: string param1 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString( RawUrl ).Get( "param2" );

Comment: Yeah, the fact that it parses only the query string part is in the name and in the documentation. It's not a bug. I'm not even sure how they could make it any clearer. `ParseQueryString` parses query strings.

Answer (score 7):

You can just use the **Uri** to get the list of the query strings or find a specific parameter.

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://www.example.com?param1=good&param2=bad");
var params = myUri.ParseQueryString();
var specific = myUri.ParseQueryString().Get("param1");
var paramByIndex = myUri.ParseQueryString().Get(2);
```

You can find more from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=net-5.0

Comment: There is no such method on Uri type in .NET 5 (as per the link) nor any newer version up to current .NET 8. It seems to incorrectly use HttpUtility API which had already been described by other answers before this answer was added.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following workaround for it to work with the first parameter too:

```
var param1 =
    HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url.Substring(
        new []{0, url.IndexOf('?')}.Max()
    )).Get("param1");
```

Answer (score 3):

Or if you don't know the URL (so as to avoid hardcoding, use the `AbsoluteUri`

Example ...

```
        //get the full URL
        Uri myUri = new Uri(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
        //get any parameters
        string strStatus = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("status");
        string strMsg = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("message");
        switch (strStatus.ToUpper())
        {
            case "OK":
                webMessageBox.Show("EMAILS SENT!");
                break;
            case "ER":
                webMessageBox.Show("EMAILS SENT, BUT ... " + strMsg);
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use .NET Reflector to view the `FillFromString` method of `System.Web.HttpValueCollection`.  That gives you the code that ASP.NET is using to fill the `Request.QueryString` collection.

Answer (score 2):

Single line LINQ solution:

```
Dictionary<string, string> ParseQueryString(string query)
{
    return query.Replace("?", "").Split('&').ToDictionary(pair => pair.Split('=').First(), pair => pair.Split('=').Last());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample that mentions what dll to include

```
var testUrl = "https://www.google.com/?q=foo";

var data = new Uri(testUrl);

// Add a reference to System.Web.dll
var args = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(data.Query);

args.Set("q", "my search term");

var nextUrl = $"{data.Scheme}://{data.Host}{data.LocalPath}?{args.ToString()}";
```

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 7

```
var uri = new Uri("http://example.com/?var1=true&var2=test&var3=3");
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
var var1 = query.Get("var1");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want in get your  QueryString on Default page .Default page means your current page url . 
you can try  this code :

```
string paramIl = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(this.ClientQueryString).Get("city");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually very simple, and that worked for me :)

```
        if (id == "DK")
        {
            string longurl = "selectServer.aspx?country=";
            var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(longurl);
            var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
            query["country"] = "DK";

            uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
            longurl = uriBuilder.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants to loop through all query strings from a string

```
        foreach (var item in new Uri(urlString).Query.TrimStart('?').Split('&'))
        {
            var subStrings = item.Split('=');

            var key = subStrings[0];
            var value = subStrings[1];

            // do something with values
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the context of an HttpRequest and using **ASPNET core**,
it can be as simple as **Request.Query["paramName"]**

I'm not sure when this was added though.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest construct I can think of without any specific dependency looks like

```cs
public Dictionary<string,string> Query(Uri queryString)
{
    return queryString.Query.Replace("?","").Split('&').ToDictionary(x=>x.Split('=')[0],x=>x.Split('=')[1]);
}
```

So for the url

```cs
var url = new Uri("http://domain.test/Default.aspx?var1=true&var2=test&var3=3");
Query(url).Dump();
```

it gives

[image]

and the parameters can be accessed as

```cs
Query(url)["var1"];
Query(url)["var2"];
Query(url)["var3"];
```

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way how to get value of know the param name:

```cs
using System.Linq;
string loc = "https://localhost:5000/path?desiredparam=that_value&anotherParam=whatever";

var c = loc.Split("desiredparam=").Last().Split("&").First();//that_value
```