# How to programmatically get the DataNavigateUrlFields property from a HyperLinkField control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, hyperlink, navigateurl

In my ASP.NET Web Forms I would like to get the `DataNavigateUrlFields` from the `HyperLinkField` control.

In order to get the control I use the following code in the `RowDataBound` event:

```
If e.Row.Cells(n).Controls(0).GetType().ToString() = "System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink" Then
     Dim linkDownload As HyperLink = DirectCast(e.Row.Cells(n).Controls(0), HyperLink)
```

The problem is that I get an **HyperLink** already "filled" so the `DataNavigateURLFormatString` (`myPage.aspx?downloadId = {0}`) and `DataNavigateUrlFields` (`downloadGuid`) are already combined in the `HyperLink.NavigateUrl` property.

Is there any way to get the `DataNavigateUrlFields` property? In case there is not, is there any function to extract the **downloadGuid** value from `HyperLink.NavigateUrl` (in short treating the **NavigateUrl** as a **QueryString**)?

VB is preferred but also answers in C# are appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you got the url, you can use Url class to manipulate it. It also allows to extract parameters and values. There's regexp option available too.

But where's downloadGuid in DataNavigateUrlFields (downloadGuid) coming from? You should get your bound object in the RowDataBound event parameters, if downloadGuid is the property, you can grap if from there.

Anyways, full event code will certainly help.

Comment: Thanks. Let's say I have the URL in NavigateUrl property. I can convert it to URL and then extract the parameters? How? Thanks!!!

Comment: totally lazy aren't we? :) 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659887/get-url-parameters-from-a-string-in-net

Comment: thanks, no I was trying another approach by using multiple Split functions with (?), (&) and (=) as separators. The first split divides the address from the parameters. Then with the second I create an array of parameters (key=value) and with the third I divide the key from the value and I can put it in a Dictionary for instance ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Why can not you get it like

```
 if(e.Row.RowType==DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                Response.Write(((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["downloadGuid"]);
```

Comment: with this method I also see the fields that are not visible in the gridview or not bounded?

Comment: You can try it yourself friend.

Comment: you didn't understand the question I guess

Comment: I understand. What I meant is try to Response.Write the above code with a column name that is not used for binding but was there in the actual datasource and see the result yourselves.