# Take the info from json file c#

Tags: c#, json

I have Json file in string (for example):

```
@{
"Url": "http://site.com/?q=windows8"
}
```

How can i take the information after `?q=` on c# (windows 8). Sorry for my English.

Comment: [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659887/get-url-parameters-from-a-string-in-net)

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659887/get-url-parameters-from-a-string-in-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do simply this :

string s = "myURL/?q=windows8";

```
// Loop through all instances of ?q=
int i = 0;
while ((i = s.IndexOf("?q=", i)) != -1)
{

    // Print out the substring. Here : windows8
    Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(i));

    // Increment the index.
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the querystring.

in Codebehind file

```
public String q
{
    get
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["q"] == null)
            return String.Empty;
        return Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["q"]);
    }
}
```

then use the line below to get the value

```
var index = ('<%=q%>');
```