# How to replace a specific character in url with a "" only after the?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to replace the `&amp;` from the url which come after `?` i.e query string.

```
Example
http://stackoverflow.com&amp;/questions/ask?a=abcd&amp;b=bcd&amp;-------->1
```

Suppose there is a Url as 1
Now I want to replace the `amp;` with ""

```
http://stackoverflow.com&amp;/questions/ask?a=abcd&b=bcd&-------->2
```

I have tried this regex as

```
\?(.*?&(amp;).*?){1,} for using Regex.Replace(......);
```

I want to replace group[2] with "".
How to do that??????????

Comment: But in the second url there is still `amp;`?

Comment: I believe you need a [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: so, you want to remove &amp; from your url ?

Comment: @Sabilv but only after ?

Comment: `&amp;` is HTML Name of `&` I thought you should see what thomas suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
string pattern = @"((?:\?|\G(?<!^))(?:[^&]+|&(?!amp;))*&)amp;";
string replacement = "$1";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

Pattern details:

```
(                         # capturing group: content after ? and before &amp; 
    (?:                   # non capturing group: entry point
        \?                # literal ?
      |                   # OR
        \G(?<!^)          # a match contiguous to a precedent match
    )
    (?:[^&]+|&(?!amp;))*  # all that is not a & or a & not followed by "amp;"
&                         # literal & before "amp;"
)
amp;
```

Comment: @user3085864: The edited version works (tested), don't forget to change the replacement pattern too.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to replace amp; by nothing, but &amp; by &.

I suppose Regex is not the correct thing to use here. See [Get url parameters from a string in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659887/get-url-parameters-from-a-string-in-net) on how to extract parameters from a URL. This will automatically convert &amp; to &