# Parse URL array parameters into C# Dictionaries

Tags: c#, .net, http, url

I have the following code to parse key value pairs from URLs:

```
    public static NameValueCollection ParseQueryString(String query)
    {
        NameValueCollection queryParameters = new NameValueCollection();
        string[] querySegments = query.Split('&');
        foreach (string segment in querySegments)
        {
            string[] parts = segment.Split('=');
            if (parts.Length > 0)
            {
                string key = parts[0].Trim(new char[] { '?', ' ' });
                string val = parts[1].Trim();

                queryParameters.Add(key, val);
            }
        }

        return queryParameters;
    }
```

I am using this function like this:

```
args = ParseQueryString("alpha=1&beta=bbbb&array%5B0%5D%5Ba%5D=1&array%5B0%5D%5Bb%5D=2&array%5B1%5D%5Ba%5D=1&array%5B1%5D%5Bb%5D=2&array%5B%5D=3&array%5B%5D=4");
foreach (var k in args.AllKeys)
{
    tw.WriteLine(k + ": " + args[k]);
}
```

Output:

```
alpha: 1
beta: bbbb
array[0][a]: 1
array[0][b]: 2
array[1][a]: 1
array[1][b]: 2
array[]: 3,4
```

I need an output of nested NameValueCollections or nested Dictionaries, so I can access the values somethis like this:

```
args = ParseQueryString("alpha=1&beta=bbbb&array%5B0%5D%5Ba%5D=1&array%5B0%5D%5Bb%5D=2&array%5B1%5D%5Ba%5D=1&array%5B1%5D%5Bb%5D=2&array%5B%5D=3&array%5B%5D=4");
var item = args.Get("array").Get(0).Get("b"); // will be "2"
```

What is the most elegant method to achieve this? I would prefer a solution without System.Web or any extra reference.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Not using libraries designed specifically for a task is usually a way of making life needlessly difficult for yourself

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get url parameters from a string in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659887/get-url-parameters-from-a-string-in-net)

Comment: @BenAaronson You're right, but I wanted my app to be compatible with 4.0 client profile. Anyway I would be happy with a System.Web solution too!

Comment: @cahinton I have seen that question, there is no mention about arrays encoded in the query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the ASP.NET MVC Framework, the default MVC parameter binder can deal with it automatically in the following way:

```
// GetData?filters[0][field]=fieldName&filters[0][type]=number&filters[0][value]=3
public ActionResult GetData(IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,string>> filters) 
{
    // todo
}
```

For more info and examples check out [this blog post](https://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-c-sharp-parse-query-string-get-parameter-arrays-square-bracket-notation-http/) that I wrote on this topic.