# Get url parameters in Windows Phone Runtime 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I have a string like this one (it's the response from the Facebook login dialog):

*msft-{ProductID}://authorize/?access_token={user-access-token}&expires_in={expiration-time-of-token}*

And I need to get the value of the access_token variable.

It's the same issue already answered here: [Get url parameters from a string in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659887/get-url-parameters-from-a-string-in-net) , but unfortunately the HttpUtility doesn't exist in Windows phone 8.1 runtime. Is there an alternative to HttpUtility.ParseQueryString?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh825884.aspx:

Use the WwwFormUrlDecoder class to break a query string into name-value pairs, based on the number and placement of "&" symbols. Each name-value pair is represented by an IWwwFormUrlDecoderEntry object.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to use Regular Expression. This should work:

```
        var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[?&]access_token(?:=(?<token>[^&]*))?");

        var match = regex.Match (responseString);

        if (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (match.Groups["token"]);
        }
```