# finding string between two specified characters in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

https://www.dgdgfdgdfg.com/profile/view?id=246925795&authType=name&authToken=sygl&trk=prof-sb-browse_map-name
here i need to split only 246925795 from these 
where string between ?id and &authType please someone help me

Comment: These are query string in the url. Can you show some code, what you have tried?

Comment: actually i am inserting multiple links using textbox while inserting i need to check using id, and these is linked in url , here only id is common, before i checked with full url i have two or more urls of the same

Comment: You have this url in a string variable?

Comment: else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtmultilines.Text))
            {
                lblcorrect.Text = "";
                lblerror.Text = "";
                string txt = txtmultilines.Text;
                string[] lst = txt.Split(new Char[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                

        foreach (string element in lst)
        {
           // Label2.Text = "<i>";
            Label2.Text += element;

Comment: @Ravidran checkout this [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y0FPc4). A very simple approach is to create a new Uri and ParseQueryString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
int start = str.IndexOf("id=") + "id=".Length;
int end = str.IndexOf("&authType");
var result = str.Substring(start, end-start);
```

---

**Better approach** is to change the URL into object representation of a [uniform resource identifier (URI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and easy access to the parts of the URI.

```
string s = @"https://www.dgdgfdgdfg.com/profile/view?id=246925795&authType=name&authToken=sygl&trk=prof-sb-browse_map-name";
Uri myUri = new Uri(s);
string sId = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("id"); //246925795
```

Comment: Only works when no other parameter ending in `id` exists before `id=` and when `id=` is actually present, when `id={id}` is directly followed by `&authType`. Not maintainable, not robust, too specific answer to benefit anyone other than OP, and worst of all: reinventing the wheel. .NET has a perfect URL parser, see [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659887/get-url-parameters-from-a-string-in-net). -1.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
string url = "https://www.dgdgfdgdfg.com/profile/view?id=246925795&authType=name&authToken=sygl&trk=prof-sb-browse_map-name";
            int a=url.IndexOf('=');
            int b=url.IndexOf('&');
            if(a!=-1 && b!=-1)
            {
                int id = Int32.Parse(url.Substring(a + 1, (b - a) - 1));
            }
```