# Is there a native way to parse key/value pairs into an array?

Tags: c#, parsing, nvp

I have a string that is the contents of a webpage in this format :

```
   value=foo&value1=bar&value2=foobar
```

What I would like to know is,  **is there a built-in way to convert this into an object/list of object/whatever so that I can loop through or access the values by keyname**

I know I can split on '&', and then split on '=', but I believe there is a built-in way to do this, I just do not know what it is.

The language I am working in is C#.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659887/get-url-parameters-from-a-string-in-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Eg.

```
NameValueCollection values = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("value=foo&value1=bar&value2=foobar");
```

Comment: What do I need to reference as `using`,  I tried `using System.Web;` and HttpUtility doesn't seem to exist.  --- edit:  Had to add a reference to System.Web as well since the built-in System.Web was missing this.