# how to get substring or part of string from a url in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have an application where uses post comments. Security is not an issue. 
string url = http://example.com/xyz/xyz.html?userid=xyz&comment=Comment

What i want is to extract the userid and comment from above string.
I tried and found that i can use `IndexOf` and `Substring` to get the desired code BUT what if the userid or comment also has = symbol and & symbol then my `IndexOf` will return number and my `Substring` will be wrong.
Can you please find me a more suitable way of extracting userid and comment.
Thanks.

Comment: No. You can get them from the Response object, I believe, as query string values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get url parameters from a string in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659887/get-url-parameters-from-a-string-in-net)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I got url using string url =
>   HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

Do not use `AbsoluteUri` property , it will give you a `string` Uri, instead use the `Url` property directly like:

```
var result = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query);
```

and then you can extract each parameter like:

```
Console.WriteLine(result["userid"]);
Console.WriteLine(result["comment"]);
```

---

For other cases when you have `string` uri then do not use string operations, instead use `Uri` class.

```
Uri uri = new Uri(@"http://example.com/xyz/xyz.html?userid=xyz&comment=Comment");
```

You can also use [`TryCreate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.trycreate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which doesn't throw exception in case of invalid Uri.

```
Uri uri;
if (!Uri.TryCreate(@"http://example.com/xyz/xyz.html?userid=xyz&comment=Comment", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out uri))
{
    //Invalid Uri
}
```

and then you can use [`System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get query string parameters:

```
 var result = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
```

Comment: I am newbie, can you please suggest how can i extract xyz and Comment from the above link after using uri

Comment: I got url using 
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
Now i do Uri uri = new Uri(@url);
var result = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);

Comment: Remember that [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is always there when you need it.

Comment: @Asbat, thats great, do not use `AbsoluteUri`, instead use `Url` directly, without converting it to string.

Comment: @Asbat, I have modified the answer

Comment: Thanks but it looks more complicated to me now :) I tried it before and it worked like a charm. instead of console i used response to see the values on webpage when testing. Great.

Comment: Can you comment on my another question, I am just asking please. thanks.

Comment: @Asbat, what other question ? I see that this is your latest question on SO

Answer (score 0):

The ugliest way is the following:

```
String url = "http://example.com/xyz/xyz.html?userid=xyz&comment=Comment";
usr = url.Split('?')[1];
usr= usr.Split('&')[0];
usr = usr.Split('=')[1];
```

But @habib version is better

Comment: But as my question say, it will fail I assume if user id or comment contain ? & =

Comment: That will be an invalid url then