# How to do conditional uri operations

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I received a userid and comment in URI from a user on a website. On button click I want to submit it but I want to make conditional so if the URI doesn't contains userid and password then I don't want to apply the URI analysis and allowing the user to type the userid and comment and press the button manually. I hope I explain correctly with my limited knowledge. The question first part is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669404/how-to-get-substring-or-part-of-string-from-a-url-in-asp-net-c-sharp/30669461?noredirect=1#comment49402260_30669461)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the previous question you are getting the query parameters as:

```
var result = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
```

You can check for `userid` and `comments` like:

```
if (result.HasKeys("userid"))
{
    // found
}
```

or you can compare against null like:

```
if (result["userid"] == null)
{
    //not found
}
```

Comment: It makes sense, so on button click i will first check if it is null then do nothing. right? BTW how can I assign userid to textbox in c# textbox.??

Comment: `textbox.Text = result["userid"];`

Comment: One more problem is that I want to skip/bypass the page if uri is available. any suggestions?

Comment: I am assuming I will copy paste my code from button click event to page load event. Inside the if condition. right?

Comment: It worked but for me the textbox.Text = result["userid"]; didnt work so i assigned it to the string variable and assigned that variable to the textbox.text and voila. all working.