# Retrieve parameters from URL using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html-agility-pack

I wanna retrieve the parameters from certain URL, how could I do this with htmlagilitypack?

Example URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=4&sort=newest

I want to get the page number and the sort value...Is it possible to do that??

The codes for load HTML page:

```
public HtmlDocument ExtractHtml(string url)
{
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);
    return doc; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `HtmlAgilityPick` since the question isn't about parsing HTML but parsing URL from which you'll get the HTML. If I understand this correctly, URL in your code is just a string, so you can use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()` to parse it and get parameters you want :

```
var parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(new Uri(url).Query);
var pageParam = parameters.Get("page");
var sortParam = parameters.Get("sort");
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xUYSsV)</kbd>**

Related question : [Get url parameters from a string in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659887/get-url-parameters-from-a-string-in-net)