# Replacing characters between two characters

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm trying to manipulate a string and I want to remove some characters in it.

Example scenario:

```
abc-def-c?p=2&x=5&z=6
```

I want to replace all chars starting from `p` and ending with the char after next `&` or `?` with empty chars. Deleting them in a way.

Input: `abc-def-c?p=2&x=5&z=6`

Output: `abc-def-c?x=5&z=6`

I know I can achieve this with `Substring` ,`IndexOf` and `Replace` but sadly there is a problem that p,x,y parts may not be in this order all the time. I need something which would find just the part and replace it.

My regex skills are not that great so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this looks liek pretty much what I want to do

Comment: @john regular expressions are no different in C#....

Comment: @john - that is PERL ones that ARE different (because it is a trendy ninja scripting language). .Net uses the standard syntax, same as the vast majority of places that support Regex..... the / characters denote that this IS a regex, its like quotes round strings... you wouldn't say that Strings are different if the quotes that start and end them are different... i hope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?<=[?&])p=.*?(?:&|$)
```

It matches `p=` preceded by `?` or `&` (`(?<=[?&])`) and followed by a string value which terminates with either `&` or end of string (`(?:&|$)`)

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5b%3f%26%5d%29p%3d.*%3f%28%3f%3a%26%7c%24%29&i=abc-def-c%3fp%3d2%26x%3d5%26z%3d6%0d%0aabc-def-c%3fx%3d5%26p%3d2%26z%3d6%0d%0aabc-def-c%3fx%3d5%26z%3d6%26p%3d2&r=)

Comment: Looks great, how can I make it include the next & char too?

Comment: @EgeBayrak you probably want the previous & char not the next one.

Answer (score 0):

I do not like Regexs so as an alternative if you are the same, you could use the class posted in one of the answers to this question;

[Get url parameters from a string in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659887/get-url-parameters-from-a-string-in-net)

Which turns Query String into a Dictionary, and then just take all keys except the one you want to ignore...

Answer (score 0):

check input contains of **p=** like this example :

**Method Shown**

```
public static string cleanString(string input)
{
    if (input.Contains("p=") && input.Contains("&"))
    {
        int startPos = input.IndexOf("p=");
        int endPos = input.IndexOf("&",startPos);
        input = input.Substring(0,startPos) + 
                                       input.Substring(endPos+1,(input.Length-1)-endPos);
    }

    return input;
}
```

**Usage**

```
cleanString("abc-def-c?p=2&x=5&z=6"));
cleanString("abc-def-c?"));
```