# C# - Using regular expression to match few specific words from url

Tags: c#

I try to make a tool that will save only urls with something like this: 
page_id?id=1'

```
http://mechanikrolniczy.cba.pl/viewtopic.php?p=16176'
http://all-tubes-jenna-haze.mzs-dgd.ru/index.php?route=product&product_id=9108429'
https://websetnet.net/page/40/?q=%2Fbs%2Fpage%2F40%2F&loginid=117cee5a78'
```

in the first URL you can see: .php?p=16176' and in the second url product_id=9108429'

and in every URL it can be different...

so I want to use regex to find only words that start with ?something=numberORwords'
I have to make sure it ends with '

I have been trying to do it for the past 2 hours, but for some reason I couldn't do it... I even came up with something like this:

```
^&/]\Wpage_id\W[=0-9]+|\W?item_id\W[=0-9]+|\W?p\W[=0-9]+\Wview\W[=0-9]+\Wno\W[=0-9]+|\Wimage_id\W[=0-9]+|\Wv\W[=0-9]+|\Wsequence\W[=0-9]+|\Wid\W[=0-9]+|\Wstart\W[=0-9]+[']
```

My code:

```
 string pattern = @"([?][\w]+[=][\w]+)[']";
        foreach(string s in urls)
        {
            Match m = Regex.Match(s, pattern);
            if (m.Success)
            {
                Valid.Add(s);
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
```

Edit:
what I try to do is to see if a website has ' at after the parameter it can be vulnerable for SQL injection..

Comment: consider using framework library routines: https://stackoverflow.com/q/659887/1132334

Comment: oh ok :) but how is it possible to do it using regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

This pattern covers all the cases that exist in your examples above.

`([?][\w]+[=][\w]+)?([&][\w]+[=][\w]+)*[']`

We are looking for the following conditions:

- `?someWord=numbersOrletters` (first capture group)
- `&someWord=numbersOrletters` (second capture group)
- ending with a `'` character  (final clause)

If your strings are trimmed and cleaned, you could add a `$` to the end of the pattern to guarantee that the `'` comes at the very end of the string.

I use [regexr.com](http://regexr.com) to build and test these things, it's a really helpful tool.

edit: This pattern captures the substring `route=product` in the second URL you posted. If you'd like to avoid this, you change the pattern to search for strings of digits `\d` rather than words `\w` (words are also allowed to contain digits, but digits cannot contain alphabetic characters).

Comment: This is a solid answer and should be selected as the correct answer.

Comment: oh, I used regex101 and I can't get for some reason any urls now, I will edit the question and show my code

Comment: Seems like you didn't include the whole expression in your code, also the last url you added doesn't end with a `'` character, if you'd like to make that condition optional, add a ? to the end of the pattern.

Comment: I messed up the whole question, what I tried to do is to check if the website has ' after the parameter it can be vulnerable for SQL injection, but I think I need to send web request or something and not check URLs from text files

Comment: This is not the right website to be posting on for advice on how to target servers for SQL injection.