# Wiremock.Net query parameter with SOQL Query

Tags: c#, .net-core, wiremock

I'm using [WireMock-Net](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net) for stubbing requests.

I want to do the following request:

Request:

```
http://localhost:63078/services/query/?q=SELECT Id from User where username='user@gmail.com'
```

The request is composed by a SOQL Query. 
Here's a snippet of what I tried to do:

```
stub.Given(Request.Create()
   .WithPath("/services/query/")
   .WithParam("q", "SELECT Id from User where username='user@gmail.com'")
   .UsingGet())
   .RespondWith(Response.Create()
      .WithStatusCode(200)
      .WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
      .WithBodyAsJson(new { Id = "5bdf076c-5654-4b3e-842c-7caf1fabf8c9" }));
```

The problem is: wiremock always replies with a 404. I've also tried using the RegexMatcher, like so:

```
   .WithPath("/services/query/")
   .WithParam("q", new WireMock.Matchers.RegexMatcher("SELECT Id from User where username.*$"))
```

But I still got a 404.

I think the problem is in the query parameter, because it has two equals "=".
Can someone help me solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest version (1.0.19) from WireMock.Net

Please retry and mark this answer as accepted if it works correctly for you.

Details: the solution is based on [Get url parameters from a string in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659887/get-url-parameters-from-a-string-in-net)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do the url encode. 
So when you are doing

```
SELECT Id from User where username='user@gmail.com'
```

you should be doing

```
SELECT %20Id%20from%20User%20where%20username%3D%27user%40gmail.com%27
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It works if I use the following expectation: 
- SELECT Id from User where username%3D%27user%40gmail.com%27

But to use it, I have to change my current implementation and, in my opinion, it is not right. I'll try another strategy or wait for the "fix" by the wiremock.net library.

Comment: @JoséSampaio : please try version 1.0.19