# How Can I get the value of input from URL parameters and use in Form ASP.NET

Tags: php, html, asp.net

How do i Do this in ASP.NET

in php (For instance) I have this HTML Page and I want to use a Url Content
Something like this

http://localhost/?name=Totten&Age=25

In Html (For PHP)  Code Looks like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
$Age = $_GET['Age']
?>
<head>

</head>

<body>
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name?;>" />
<input type="Age" name="Age" value="<?php echo $Age?;>" />
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Now i want to get the same thing in ASP.NET (WebForm)

How is this Done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get url parameters from a string in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659887/get-url-parameters-from-a-string-in-net)

Comment: When I googled on your title, I found _many_ posts about this. Did you do any research and made any attempts before asking?

Comment: The best practice to handle this will depend on which variation of asp.net you're using. Is it MVC? Razor pages? WebForms? Please clarify. Actually also if you search yourself online mentioning your specific version then you can find tutorials showing this kind of thing anyway

Answer (score 0):

in asp.net, you can/would use code like this:

```
dim strName as string = Request.QueryString("Name")
dim intAge as integer = Request.QueryString("Age")
```