# Single Regex with multiple match patterns

Tags: c#, regex

Regex is hard :)

What I have right now is a string value that I am succesfuly matching values on specific keys. I need to expand my regex to match a using a value rather than a key.

```
https://www.me.com/?name=bob&identify=bob1&test=email@me.com&validKey=validValue
```

The current Regex being applied is

```
((name|identify|test)(=|%3D)[^&]*)
```

What I want to add/extend is to match any values that contain an @ symbol. I wont know what the 'key' is in as its dynamic so I cant just add 'badKey' into the matched pattern. So an example input for this would be:

```
https://www.me.com/?name=bob&identify=bob1&test=email@me.com&validKey=validValue&badKey=test2@test.com
```

Basically I want to match all the existing parts and then also the 'badKey' one. I know I can run the string through a second Regex but for performance sake I would like this to be a single pattern.

**Any help here would be appreciated.**

Comment: You've tagged C#, so is there a reason you're using Regex rather than [parsing the query string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/659929/8126362)?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay This input string was just an example it may not always be a URI. I need similar logic in several places. I was hoping for a resolution on this one and I could then understand how its done on a URI and then apply the logic elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a pattern that will match specifically emails and not just values that contain an @ symbol

```
(name|identify|test)(=|%3D)[^&|^%26]*|((=|%3D)(\\w+([-+.]\\w+)*[@|%40]\\w+([-.]\\w+)*\\.\\w+([-.]\\w+)*)[^&|^%26]*)
```

Answer (score -1):

U can use the String.Split to break down by key=value pairs (split by "&") and processing each pair

Comment: I asked specifically for Regex. In my case if I had to break down each and every string the overhead would be too much. The Regex ends up being much more efficient.

Comment: Hmm... IMHO regular expression is not so effective, but.... Then I would use something like this: [?&](\w+)\=([^&]+)

Comment: Hi @Dimitry,  that Regex will find everything between the & symbols and not just the bad actor values I want to exclusively look for. But thanks for trying. Also Regular expressions definitely have their place else they wouldn't exist or be supported.  In my case I need to use one as it is more efficient than normal string functions.

Comment: Just a side note if you read my question I am looking for keys that have specific values and then also specifically any value that is an email not just things between the Amp symbol