# Associate windows application with URL click in browser

Tags: c#, .net, windows, desktop-application, desktop

How to associate custom windows forms app to particular URL,
e.g. myprogram:?xt=myparams

```
<a href="myprogram:?xt=myparams">Open my program</a>
```

whenever user clicks on the links from any browser it opens up `myprogram` windows app passing the parameters in querystring(`?`)

Is it possible to associate windows app with a URL in browser without installing any plugins in browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a custom protocol in Windows and associate it with your program. You have to do this via the Windows registry. Either manually, with a .reg-file or with some kind of installer program which creates the entry for each end user.

Details about this are already answered here [How do I register a custom URL protocol in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows)

Having that registry entry should affect all browsers and will make them open your program whenever a link is using your custom protocol.

Also note that the full URL will be passed to your program as a command line argument. You have to parse that string manually. I assume you're using C# because you used it as a tag. The .NET framework provides methods for parsing URLs and getting the parameters [Get URL parameters from a string in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659887/get-url-parameters-from-a-string-in-net)