# How to get the codefromURL value for Docusign eSignature API Integration

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpclient, docusignapi

In the DocuSign eSignature API Integration, to get the OAuth access token, we are supposed to pass two parameters ***code*** and ***grant_type*** as per their API Specification.

The Parameter ***code*** is the resultant of the below url that I am loading everytime in the browser and copying and pasting. The other parameter ***grant_type*** is a static string.

URL to generate the ***code***

[https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id={my-client-id}&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/callback](https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=%7Bmy-client-id%7D&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/callback)

so, whenever I load this URL in my browser, the redirection will happen to a new page and the browser URL will show like this below.

[https://www.example.com/callback?code={unique-code}](https://www.example.com/callback?code=%7Bunique-code%7D)

Now, everytime, I am copying this unique-code and specify in my Web Application as a part of my developement in the ***code input parameter***.

But, in real time, how to fetch this code so that I can integrate in my asp.net C# application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Get URL parameters from a string in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659887/get-url-parameters-from-a-string-in-net) answers this question for C#, let me summarize:

Use this code:

```
string param1 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("code");
```